# ORACLE APEX: Getting the value from page item and use it to another page item

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-19.1, oracle-apex-18.2

I have two forms:

first one:

- 5000_Works,
- with items:

  - P5000_ID,
  - P5000_Working_Date,
  - P5000_QTY

and the second form:

- 5001_Tasks,
- with items:

  - P5001_ID,
  - P5001_QTY

I open the second form from the first one and i want to put the value of `P5000_QTY` to the second page item `P5001_QTY`.
How can i do that?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

One option is to create a button which - when pushed - redirects to another page in this application. When you click on the "Target" (in "Behavior" properties section), you can tell Apex to:

- navigate to page `5001`
- set item `P5001_QTY` to value `&P5000_QTY.` Note leading ampersand `&` and trailing dot `.`

And that's it ...

If it isn't a button but a branch, the principle is the same - using the Link Builder you'd do exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I do exactly what you write to me, but nothing happens ....P5001_QTY is still empty...